# Unable to login FirebaseAuth on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, firebase

I currently get this error when using FirebaseAuth:

Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match stored id " UserInfo=0x1f5cff20 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: remote_app_id does not match stored id }

I did check again to ensure that my bundleid matched exactly (even case match) with the configuration in facebook.  So it's not a facebook app setting issue regarding the bundleid.

I also tried deleting the facebook app / logging out of FB in iOS and logging back on.  But this doesn't change the result.

These are the APIs that I am using:
Firebase.framework-1.0.0.zip
FirebaseAuthClient.framework-1.0.0.zip

Let me know if there's anything I should definitely try out.  Thanks!

```
[self.authClient loginToFacebookAppWithId:@"12345" permissions:@[@"email"]
                 withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAUser *user) {

                     if (error != nil) {
                         // There was an error logging in
                         NSLog(@"There was an error logging in: code = %d", [error code]);

                             NSLog(@"%@", error);


                     } else {
                         // We have a logged in facebook user
                         NSLog(@"We have a logged in facebook user");

                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: Can you double check that you have Facebook auth enabled and your app id and secret set up in Forge (log in to your Firebase account, click on your firebase and then click on Auth)? If that all looks correct, can you email me (greg at firebase dot com) the name of your Firebase and your bundle Id and I'll take a look?

Comment: Yeah appid/secret already in my firebase.  Thanks for checking though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try grabbing the latest FirebaseAuthClient (v1.0.1) from here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html and trying again? We've made some updates that should help.

Comment: Yes, this did solve my problem.  Thank you!  I'd vote this up, but I don't yet have the rep :)  All the best guys!